# How to manage company software upgrade

Tags: windows, linux, package-manager

I'm a developer and I work on a company that distribute its own software suite.
What I'm looking for, and I cannot find, is a software that installed on clients PC and a company server manages upgrades.

On server side, I'm thinking something like a place/folder where we can drop a new software release, decorated with some meta info like software version, etc...

On client side, an application that stays on system tray and when internet connection is available, automatically check the server for software upgrades/new versions. 
If present, prompt the user for install.

Best would be a Windows/Linux solution. If not present, Windows is the main target.

Comment: Normally you would build a check for new version into your software suite

Comment: It could be a possible solution, but since we release a suite of software, I'm looking for an additional software that prompt the user for update one or more